# Chrome "Secure DNS" setting in v83 breaks access to internal websites

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I have found that if I attempt to access a web based service internal to my home network then Chrome will fail to properly resolve the URL. An example would be if I were to try to browse to my Plex server using its fqdn; plex.mydomain.com. This is only if the "Secure DNS" setting is enabled. It appears to be directing my web requests to a DNS server outside my network. Rather than taking me to my Plex server web frontend I'll actually be redirected to a page on my pfsense router with an error warning me of a potential DNS Rebinding attack.

I run my own internal DNS server. It's a simply Windows 2012r2 server. Everything on my internal network is pointed to this server, which is configured to forward requests to Google's DNS server for records that it doesn't know about.

I like the idea of using Secure DNS (or DNS over HTTPS). But I can't seem to use it for the above reason. I'm wondering though, if I were to configure my internal DNS server to support DNSSEC then that might fix the problem. I'm thinking I'd also need to adjust my Chrome settings to use my internal DNS server for it's Secure DNS service. Does that all sound correct?

Has anyone else observed this problem?

Comment: There appears to be some misuse of terms, leading to confusion while reading: If accessing the LAN Plex server via an FQDN, it's not a LAN request, but a WAN request... a `<hostname>.<localdomain>` could be used, but if you're trying to access media on the Plex server from within the LAN, and it is configured with an FQDN as well, accessing it via the latter is vastly inefficient _(it should be accessed via IP or `<hostname>.<localdomain>`, else the information flow is LANclient <=> WAN <=> LANplex <=> WAN <=> LANclient)_.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Provided the Plex server & client are on the same LAN, the LAN subnet's DNS server should not be configured to forward RFC1918 requests outside of the LAN. RFC1918 requests should be exempt from Chrome's DNSSEC AFAIK, as I'm able to access local router WebUIs that aren't utilizing DNSSEC via Chrome. If unable to do so, review pfSense's DNS server's config and applicable logs _(increase the applicable logs' verbosity if available)_, as well as checking out the [pfSense](https://forum.netgate.com/) and [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/networking/pfsense) forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable DNS-over-HTTPS support on your DNS server in order for this to work. If your local DNS server doesn't support DoH, Chrome will automatically upgrade the request and bypass your local DNS settings, and use Google's preferred DoH servers. Unfortunately, Microsoft DNS does not currently offer this.

Assuming that you have public DNS set up for plex.mydomain.com, what's happening for you is that Chrome tests to see if your Windows DNS server supports DoH. Chrome sees that it doesn't, then fires the request off to 8.8.8.8 using DoH, which resolves your public IP. Your client then tries to connect to your public IP, rather than the internal one, and pfsense blocks what could be considered a rebinding attack. If you're using a desktop, rather than a laptop which will sometimes need to connect externally, you may be able to get around this by adding the local IP of your Plex server into your hosts file. Generally entries in the hosts file never make it to the OS level DNS. But given that Chrome is already substituting in its own DNS resolver, you may be out of luck with that.

More information about how DoH works in Chrome:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/dns-over-https

Specifically from that page:

1. Chrome will have a table to map non-DoH DNS servers to their equivalent DoH DNS servers.
2. Per this table, if the system’s recursive resolver is known to support DoH, Chrome will upgrade to the DoH version of that resolver. In other words, this would upgrade the protocol used for DNS resolution while keeping the user’s DNS provider unchanged. It’s also important to note that DNS over HTTPS does not preclude its operator from offering features such as family-safe filtering.
3. On some platforms, **this may mean that where Chrome previously used the OS DNS resolution APIs, it now uses its own DNS implementation in order to implement DoH**.
4. A group policy will be available so that Administrators can disable the feature as needed
5. End-users will have the ability to control the feature from the settings page (e.g. disable, auto-upgrade, choose or specify a specific provider)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  It sounds like the answer then is if adjusting my hosts file doesn't fix it then my only options are to either 1. Disable the feature until Microsoft DNS catches up and starts supporting DoH; which would likely require that I upgrade my DNS server to at least Windows 2019 server or 2. Replace my DNS server with another one that does support DoH.